# prove path connected crossing line

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

If $U\subseteq \mathbb{R^n} $ and path connected,

with $V\subseteq_{open} U$ , $U\backslash V\subseteq_{open} U$

then $ V=U $or $\phi $

Here are my thoughts, but not working.

Let $ x \in V$ and $ y \in U\backslash V $, and let a path x to y .

When the path go from x to y, there must have a problem at crossing line.

I try to proof by the thought, but I failed.

Can someone give me details?

Comment: So think in this way. Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ be your path. Let $A=\gamma^{-1}(V)$ and $B=\gamma^{-1}(U\setminus V)$. Note that $A$ and $B$ are both open and they are disjoint, but $[0,1]$ is connected.

But in fact you don't even need to consider the path. Path connectedness implies connectness, so you just have the result.

Comment: In case you dont want to use connectedness, think in this way. Let $x$ be the infimum of in $[0,1]\cap B$. Since $1\in B$, the set is non-empty. Since $0\in A$, the infinmum cannot be $0$. Then the infimum cannot be in $B$. Then it is in $A$. However, by the property of an open set, there exists a small ball centered at that point completely contained in $A$, which contradicts the openness and disjointness